# Custom Loss Functions in Keras

Tags: keras

I have tried to write my own custom loss function in Keras. But writing complex loss functions are normally requiring deep knowledge of TensorFlow and Keras Backend. Do I need to study them to write my own loss function or is there an alternative method for writing custom loss functions for neural networks in Keras?
My loss function requires the probability of prediction of all classes and some way to point out the probability corresponding to the label class.

Comment: Yes, you need to learn backend functions, there is no work around that.

Comment: If you have the loss function coded using numpy you could use `tf.py_func` or lambda, but still is better to use backend function and most of them work like numpy functions.